# convert json to c# object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

My c# model

```
public class Student
{
  public string id{get;set;}
  [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("ref")]
  public int @ref{get;set;}
}
```

My ASP.Net Core API method

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromBody] Student stu)
{
   var reference = stu.@ref;
   //Here stu.@ref is always 0.
   //JSON to C# model conversion doesnt work
}
```

Following is the request body

```
{
  "id":"74A",
  "ref":41
}
```

C# doesnt allow to declare variable name "ref", so i declared as "@ref" and decorated it with JsonPropertyName("ref"). However json to c# model deserialsation doesnt map ref to @ref.

Any solution or work around.

Comment: Seems to be invalid json. 
Have you tried https://json2csharp.com ?

Comment: Works on [my internet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yt7ofY).

Comment: "Here stu.@ref is always 0." but what about stu.id ?

Comment: stu.id is "74A". Json to c# model works for id property

Comment: Please post your actual code. `System.Text.Json.Serializer.JsonPropertyName` is not the right namespace, instead of `Serializer` it should be `Serialization`, which leads me to think there might be other problems as well. Do know that the *actual* property name of that property will be just `ref`, the `@` prefix is just to get the compiler to not treat it as the reserved keyword, the `@` will not actually be a part of the property name.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have updated the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don' t change your property @ref to reference or something else? there are plenty another words, you don't need to use c# reserved

```
public class Student
{
  public string id{get;set;}
  [System.Text.Json.Serializer.JsonPropertyName("ref")]
  public int reference {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You `JSON` string is missing a `"` after `id` and therefore it is not parsing it correctly since it is invalid. Once you get the correct `JSON` string, then you should be able to parse it correctly to your `Student` class.

You can verify if your JSON is valid here: https://jsonlint.com/